# Shared vs Private Directive in openmp

Tags: openmp

If variables are **`shared`** by default ([See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753210/openmp-set-global-sharing-default)), is it necessary to use the shared directive in an openmp directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite true, as the answer to the question you refer to asserts, that all variables are shared.  For example, the iteration variable on `for`/`do` loops is made private.  Variables declared within a parallel region are private.

So now there is doubt in your mind about which variables are, by default, shared and which private.  No, it is not necessary to add a `default` clause to OpenMP directives.  But it is often, especially when taking one's early steps with OpenMP, advisable to use `default(none)` and to explicitly state the accessibility of all variables.